# batch split filename on regex

Tags: regex, batch-file, split

I was assigned a task to catalog songs by artists and song name.
I was given song files and had to take the artist's name out of the file by the delimiter (' - ')(space hyphen space).

songs:
Artist.A - song 1.wav
Artist B - song-2.wav
Artist---C - song$B.mp3
Artists$D - song-4.mp3

so far this what I came up with, yet I couldn't get the string 'Artists B':

```
dir /b "C:\songs\" | for /f "delims=" %a ('findstr /c:" - "') do ( echo %a )
```

It takes songs under C:\songs\ and makes sure they got " - " in them.

I'm still very new to batch and read the 'man' page for 'for', but I couldn't find an answer.
Also I looked up and found something to do with `%a: - :^&REM #%`, but couldn't get it to work.

Hope someone could help me out.

Comment: Yes that can be tricky if their are other hypens within the artist name. Would be no problems if there was just a single hyphen between the Artist name and song name.

Comment: yeah, if so the answer was just "delims=-"

Comment: Using [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) - `jren "^.+? - +" ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\* - *" '
 ) DO (
 SET "fulltitle=%%a"
 SET "song=!fulltitle:* - =!"
 CALL SET "artist=%%fulltitle: - !song!=%%"
 ECHO artist=!artist!
 ECHO song  =!song!
 ECHO TITLE =!fulltitle!
 ECHO ------------------
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Perform a `dir` command in `/b` basic form `/a-d` without directories, and assign the names found to `%%a`.

Copy `%%a` to `fulltitle` to allow substringing. `delayedexpansion` has been invoked to allow access to the run-time values of the variables. With each name found, the title will be that part of the full title that appears after the `-`, so replace "*whatever* - " with *nothing*. Then replace " - *thetitle*" with nothing using a `call` to allow the replaced part to be variable, leaving the artist name.

Report results.

Answer (score 0):

The [`for /F` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) uses characters to split strings, not strings. The [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) does not split strings, it always returns full lines that contain matches.

Given that the artist name does not contain <kbd>SPACE</kbd> +  `-` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, you could replace that sub-string by a single character, which cannot occur in the file name (for instance, `|`), then split the string at this character, using `for /F`, like this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_LOCATION=C:\songs"
set "_MASK=* - *.*"

rem // Loop through the matching files:
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D "%_LOCATION%\%_MASK%"
') do (
    rem // Store the pure file name:
    set "FILE=%%~nF"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose exclamation marks:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Replace ` - ` by `|` and split the file name at the first `|`:
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=|" %%A in ("!FILE: - =|!") do (
        endlocal
        rem // Store the artist, which is the first file name portion:
        set "ARTIST=%%A"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Extract song title, which is all behind the first ` - `:
        set "SONG=!FILE:* - =!"
        rem // Return the result:
        echo(Artist: !ARTIST!
        echo(Title:  !SONG!
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```